# Change CPanel Code Editor

Tags: plugins, cpanel, code-editor

**Description:**
I have been using the CPanel code editor for over a year and I feel the default editor doesn't have enough developer tools for me. Is there a plugin I could use to edit my files more effectively? I've never used any CPanel plugins such as cms.

Comment: try latest version editor its have great development features

Answer (score 0):

**You might not be able to change the default cPanel code editor straight away** it has some language support but I can agree that it's not for Developers.

I would recommend that you try switching over to another Editor / IDE.

A nice free one is [Atom](https://atom.io/) - it's a project built on JavaScript (Electron) by GitHub